# How to monitor for swipe gesture globally in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsevent

I'd like to make an OSX application that runs in the background and performs some function when a swipe down with four fingers is detected on the trackpad.

Seems easy enough. Apple's docs show almost exactly this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html). Their example monitors for mouse down events. As a simple test, I put the following in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in my `AppDelegate`.

```
void (^handler)(NSEvent *e) = ^(NSEvent *e) {
  NSLog(@"Left Mouse Down!");
};

[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDownMask handler:handler];
```

This works as expected. However, changing `NSLeftMouseDownMask` to `NSEventMaskSwipe` does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe look at `CGEventTapCreate()` and friends? (In `CoreGraphics/CGEvent.h`)

Comment: @nielsbot Worth a look indeed.  But I believe `CGEvent` is the low-level API on which the `NSEvent` class sits upon.

Comment: yes--true. but the question was about detecting a swipe, it didn't specifically say it had to use `NSEvent`. Anyway, that's why I posted as a comment not an answer.

Comment: @nielsbot  It wasn't a critic by any means... I wasn't trying to dismiss it (bad choice of words on my part I guess).  I was trying to add more info by stating the relationship between both. :)

Comment: no worries--I didn't take it the wrong way. just clarifying. I probably sounded harsh :)

Comment: anyway--I looked and it doesn't look like the CGEvent stuff covers gestures. The events must get into Cocoa by another route? OP might be SOL.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts guys. It's too bad that this isn't an option. I guess I'll go with key-down events to trigger my app, which is actually better in that the users hands won't need to leave the keyboard. In fact, I think I will take more inspiration from vim on this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the documentation for NSEvent's [+addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a) gives a list of event it supports and `NSEventMaskSwipe` is not listed so... it's to be expected that it not work.

While the API obviously supports the tracking of gesture *locally* within your own application (through [`NSResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000015-SW35)), I believe gestures can't be track globally by design.  Unlike key combinations, there are much lower forms/types of gestures... essentially only:

- pinch in/out  (`NSEventTypeMagnify`)
- rotations  (`NSEventTypeRotation`)
- directional swipes with X amount of fingers  (`NSEventTypeSwipe`)

There's not as much freedom.  With keys, you have plenty of modifiers (control, option, command, shift) and the whole alphanumeric keys making plenty of possible combinations so it'd be easier to reduce the amount of conflicts with local-events and global-events.  Similarly, mouse events are region-based;  clicking in one region can easily be differenciated from clicking in another region (from both the program's and user's point-of-view).

Because of this *lower possible combination* of touch events, I believe Apple might purposely be restricting global (as in, one app, responding to one or more gestures for the whole system) usage for its own usage (Mission Control, Dashboard, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did see that list in the docs, but I was confused since it says `In OS X 10.6...`. I was hoping the situation would be different in 10.7+. It seems reasonable that an app could be triggered by some global gesture, similar to Mission Control, even if only with a modifier key pressed as well. Is there a way around this? Even if it's not compliant with Apple's guidelines?

Comment: You mean besides hacking the system?!  I'm afraid I don't.  Sorry I couldn't give you the answer you were looking for.